# Android showing Error :Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

The `ArrayList` was null, now I am updating the code as per the suggestions by you but a new error is coming up:

```
private HashMap<String, String> wordList;
private ArrayList<String> hashWordArray;
private void readFile() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordsdata));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split("/t");
        wordList.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    readFile();
    hashWordArray = new ArrayList<String>(wordList.keySet());
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hashWordArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This is the error displayed :

```
Process: com.example.archit.dictionarytwo, PID: 17915
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.archit.dictionarytwo/com.example.archit.dictionarytwo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    at com.example.archit.dictionarytwo.MainActivity.readFile(MainActivity.java:23)
    at com.example.archit.dictionarytwo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: Where does the stack trace show you the error? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?
I see no method call to `.size()` in the code you've shown.

Comment: Updated my code but a new error is coming up

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you thought that you initialized *hashWordArray* `ArrayList` in `readFile()` but you never call `readFile()`.

When you write :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hashWordArray);
```

*hashWordArray* `ArrayList` has never been initialized.

So change `onCreate` method to :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    readFile();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hashWordArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can share the complete logs. One error which i found in your code is that the HashMap.Add this statement after you initialize the HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String,String> wordList;
wordList = new HashMap<>();
```

Can you try this?

`

Comment: you have to initialize the wordlist  (wordList = new HashMap<>();)  .. before going inside the while. In the readfile() method. I see that is still missing? Can you point out where it is ?